# Everything in Eclipse runs as Junit

Tags: android, eclipse, junit

Last time I used eclipse I run some Junit tests for my coursera course. Since then when I try to run an android app in eclipse it runs as Junit.In the "Run As" menu I get no choices available ("None applicable"). Is there some configuration I have to change in order to run everything as Android App without having to reconfigure every single app manually ,every time I run it for the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to Run configuration by right click on your project then > run as > Run configuration

 [image]

then run configuration window will pop up then delete Junit config profiel it's under Junit
then add what ever config you want like android app by right click on android application then add new [image]

Comment: Deleting the JUnit Core profile was the solution.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just change the profile name. If You Choose "Run Configuration", You can put different names and which app should run inside.

[image]

Comment: This is what I did ,but is there some way to go back and configure all my existing projects or do I have to do the same procedure for every single one of them?